# Obtain OAuth2 token from third parties

Tags: apigee, apigee-baas, apigee127

Could you tell me where I can see how to implement oauth2 management for a third party, that is, the image is the black point.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlgFs.png)

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer from the apigee portal ->
https://community.apigee.com/questions/81938/obtain-oauth2-token-from-third-parties.html